# how to initialize Database variable in flutter app

Tags: flutter

I'm a beginner in flutter, i want to use SQlite database using sqflite package in my Flutter App, when I declare the _database variable with this syntax `static Database _database;`, I get a compilation error saying _database must be initialized except I don't know how to initialize it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise a database like this

```
// Set path of the database
var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
String path = join(databasesPath, 'demo.db');

// Load the database (or create a new one, if it does not yet exist)
Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
  // When creating the db, create the table
  await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE Test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INTEGER, num REAL)');
});
```

Of course, you will need to modify SQL command depending on your desired database structure.
After initialisation, you can perform all your database operations. But don't forget to close the connection in the end via

```
await database.close();
```

More info can be found on the [documentation page](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) of the `sqflite` package. This is often a good place to start your research.

Answer (score 0):

Before reading and writing data to the database, open a connection to the database. This involves two steps:

Define the path to the database file using getDatabasesPath() from the sqflite package, combined with the join function from the path package.
Open the database with the openDatabase() function from sqflite.

Note: In order to use the keyword await, the code must be placed inside an async function. You should place all the following table functions inside void main() async {}.

```
// Avoid errors caused by flutter upgrade.
// Importing 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' is required.
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
// Open the database and store the reference.
final database = openDatabase(
  // Set the path to the database. Note: Using the `join` function from the
  // `path` package is best practice to ensure the path is correctly
  // constructed for each platform.
  join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'doggie_database.db'),
);
```

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Opening a database

A database is a single file represented by a path in the file system

```
// File path to a file in the current directory
String dbPath = 'sample.db';
DatabaseFactory dbFactory = databaseFactoryIo;

// We use the database factory to open the database
Database db = await dbFactory.openDatabase(dbPath);
```

The db object is ready for use.

More information [Here](https://github.com/tekartik/sembast.dart/blob/master/sembast/doc/open.md).