# how to initialize SQLite Database variable in flutter app

Tags: flutter

I'm a beginner in flutter, i want to use SQlite database using sqflite package in my Flutter App, when I declare the`_database` variable with this syntax `static Database _database;` , I get a compilation error saying `_database` must be initialized except I don't know how to initialize it ?

```
class AnnonceDataBase {

  AnnonceDataBase._();
  static final AnnonceDataBase instance = AnnonceDataBase._();
  static Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;
  }

  initDB() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    return await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'annonce_database.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        return db.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE annonce (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, titre Text,prix INTEGER, description TEXT, idAnnonceur INTEGER, active INTEGER)");
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to initialize Database variable in flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74337870/how-to-initialize-database-variable-in-flutter-app)

Comment: It seems that you posted the same question twice. Instead, you could go back and edit your first question to include the code snippet for context.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer here, because without the code this answer would seem out of context on your other question.

You should replace

```
static Database _database;
```

with

```
static Database? _database;
```

to mark the static variable as an optional (can be null).